# How to add bold and normal text in one line using drawString method in reportlab (python)

Tags: python, canvas, reportlab, richtext

I am new to `reportlab` lib, I am learning it simultaneously working on a college project.
I have created a desktop application in `wxpython`, which result in saving data in PDF.

I want to add 2 lines in my pdf. Where line starts with a user input called name, then some words, again at 2nd line some words, user name and then again some words...

I tried use some of `Paragraph` and `canvas` methods and classes but I wasn't able to get the desired output.

***Desired output:***

**Alex** is working on college project.

reportlab is very good lib, **Alex** liked it.

**My code:**

```
import os
import reportlab
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Registered font family
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Vera', 'Vera.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraBd', 'VeraBd.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraIt', 'VeraIt.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('VeraBI', 'VeraBI.ttf'))
# Registered fontfamily
registerFontFamily('Vera',normal='Vera',bold='VeraBd',italic='VeraIt',boldItalic='VeraBI')

# Output pdf file name.
can = canvas.Canvas("Bold_Trail.pdf", pagesize=A4)

# Setfont for whole pdf.
can.setFont('Vera', 12)

# student name variable.
student_name ="Alex"

# Content.
line1 = " is working on college project."
line2 = "Reportlab is very good lib, "
line3 = " liked it.<br>"

# Joining whole content together.
content = "<strong>" + student_name + "</strong>" + line1
content2 = line2 + "<strong>"+student_name + "</strong>" + line3

# drawString location calculation.
x = 0; y = 8.5 * 72

# First string.
can.drawString(x,y, content)

y = y - 72

# Second String.
can.drawString(x,y, content2)

# Create PDF.
can.save()
```

Is there any other way except using XML method `<strong>` or `<b>` that do not work in the above program?

The words should remain on one line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the `setFont` method of the `canvas` object, to set the font to `Bold` when needed, and `Normal` otherwise.

*** UPDATE ***

In order to calculate the right value for `x`, you can use the `stringWidth` method, that calculates the length of the string given its content, the font name and the font size. You will have to import it from `reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics`:

```
[...]
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import stringWidth
[...]

# student name variable.
student_name = 'Alex'

# Content.
line1 = " is working on college project."
line2 = "Reportlab is very good lib, "
line3 = " liked it"

# drawString location calculation.
x = 0
y = 8.5 * 72

# First string.
can.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 8)
can.drawString(x, y, student_name)
can.setFont('Helvetica', 8)
textWidth = stringWidth(student_name, 'Helvetica-Bold', 8) 
x += textWidth + 1
can.drawString(x, y, line1)

y = y - 72

# Second String.
x = 0
can.setFont('Helvetica', 8)
can.drawString(x, y, line2)
textWidth = stringWidth(line2, 'Helvetica', 8) 
x += textWidth + 1
can.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 8)
can.drawString(x, y, student_name)
textWidth = stringWidth(student_name, 'Helvetica-Bold', 8) 
x += textWidth + 1
can.setFont('Helvetica', 8)
can.drawString(x, y, line3)

# Create PDF.
can.save()
```

Or you could have a look at `ParagraphStyle` and `Paragraph` (`from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle`, `from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph`) but I am not sure if you can concatenate two different styles in the same string.

Comment: **Thank you,** it worked !
I will also looking for suggested class (Paragraph).

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah I'm pretty sure there is a way to achieve that using `ParagraphStyle`, it would probably be more elegant...

Comment: One question.
Why you multiplied student name with 5 ?
and later with 4.5 ?
I didn't understood what that value is for.

Comment: That's what I meant with "calculation of `x` can definitely be improved": I put these values to fit with the name "Alex". Please see my updated answer for a more dynamic solution.

Comment: Thank you again. 
Now I am clear with this concept :)

Answer (score 6):

I found a way to format the Paragraph text with XML tags. Firstly you need to register the font family then it should work. Below I downloaded a group of .ttf files as an example and registered them, after that, the XML tags worked properly.

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('OpenSansR', 'OpenSans-Regular.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('OpenSansL', 'OpenSans-Light.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('OpenSansB', 'OpenSans-Bold.ttf'))
registerFontFamily('OpenSans', normal='OpenSansR', bold='OpenSansB', italic='OpenSansL', boldItalic='OpenSansB')
```